# front end vs. back end definition

Tags: c#, asp.net

In IT school and am getting conflicting answers on exactly what the front end and the back end in software development are. I have searched the web including this site, and have asked several knowledgeable people, and the core answer I get is that anything that runs on a web server is the front end, while anything that runs on the application server or the database server is the back end. So front end = how the site looks and back end = making the site work, but I get conflicting answers if .net windows forms and asp.net forms are all front end development or a combination of front end and back end.

To ask a specific question, with asp.net forms, is the aspx code the front end and the c# code behind the back end in these applications? Or is asp.net all front end? Thank you.

Comment: Completely opinion based... Walk to a street - on your left is so called "left end", to your right "right end"... now argue with a person to the right if space between you is "left end" of the street or "right end" :)

Comment: It is hard to say these days due to rich ***client-side Framework*** like Angular and ***Serverless Architecture*** like FireBase.

Comment: "front end = how the site looks and back end = making the site work" Yup, Pretty much that's it.

Comment: @Win Angular is a front-end framework (using client side as the definition of front end) though it can contain some logic that is not about the UI. The server it talks to is still the back-end. Can't say for FireBase :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET How do you define Angular written with TypeScript *(transpile at serverside)* calling  *Serverless* Firebase? It becomes hard to draw the line.

Comment: @Win With typescript I believe the transpilation is usually done at dev time, regardless; the lines are certainly *blurred*.

Answer (score 6):

In a web application, I typically use the following definitions:

**Front-end**: Runs on client (users) computer

**Back-end**: Runs on server

In a traditional ASP application all of the markup (Razor) gets converted into HTML on the *back-end* before being sent to the client, so the vast majority of the work is done there. The actual HTML parsing (done by the browser) and any JavaScript is still part of the front-end though.

In *general*, a front-end is the UI and its logic, and the back-end is the rest of the program/system (Business logic, data access, etc)

Comment: Essentially you can also break the server side code into `Front-end` and `back-end`. Can't you?

Comment: @RBT To a certain extent; sure. You want to be careful because part of understanding ASP is understanding that nearly everything occurs on the back-end (ie, the server).

Answer (score 5):

In general - everything that runs on the server is considered back-end and everything that runs on the browser is front-end.

Usually - the back end code generates a code the will run on the browser, which is a front end code.

asp.net is considered back end, and if it generates html/css/javascript - these will run on the browser and thus they are front end.

Comment: Even in server side development - I always used to think that *.aspx, *aspx.cs and *.js files constitute front-end. Domain services, business logic layer, data access layer, ORM (e.g. entity framework), database constitute back-end. Was that not a correct understanding?

Comment: @RBT JS is definitely front-end, aspx.cs absolutely back-end (all server); the aspx files themselves are weird because they are processed on the backend and the result of that is rendered on the front-end (as HTML)

Comment: *.aspx are really a weird species as they also contain server side code using `<% %>` markers :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on several things. I.e. what application are you referring to (i.e. desktop app, web app, API, mobile app) since each of those may group-in slightly different things under the front-end / back-end categories.

In web apps we refer to any UI (client exposed) portion of the application code as **front-end**. So for example all HTML, jS, css and other user interface (view) related files should be under the umbrella of the front-end (hence the front-end developer - the guy/girl who is pulling his/her hair over cross-browser compatibility :) etc.)

The business logic, data manipulation and processing (models, controllers, db objects, etc.) are commonly refereed to as **back-end**.

You may check out Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends)